# Invoke the browser back button in PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form which sends the user to a different form incase they don't complete it to go back to the form and complete anything that was missed. Now unless the user presses the browser back button the page is loaded fresh which mean any data gets lost.

Pretty much when they come back to the previous page, anything they already filled in should stay intact.

I have the following two pages:

Page 1:

```
<?PHP

echo "<a href='page2.php'>NEXT</a>";
echo "<input type=text size=25 name=txt />";
?>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
$refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$lastlink = "<a href='$refer'>BACK</a>";

echo $lastlink;
?>
```

On page two if i click BACK to come back to page 1, anything entered in page 1 will be lost which I do not want.
How do I work around it without using Javascript? with Javascript?
I know in javascript  I can use

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">BACK</a>
```

But is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [html5 history api](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html). History api + ajax is great combination

Comment: Any idea how to create it because I am not to this whole thing on history api :|

Comment: You can push page states and later on navigation in history, onpopstate event is called and you can get recently pushed state and use it. You can read provided tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a session to store `$_POST` on submit and check if it is set on page-load of the first form.

Comment: If i had 50 textboxes, using post will be really time consuming and slow but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I am usually satisfied with:

```
history.back(-1);
```

Sending back to a previous page using Server-Side logic, is not a good approach to do, so I will disencourage it.